# Simplify matrix expression with assumptions

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am trying to simplify complex matrix expressions with some assumptions (such as matrix is a rotation matrix). I am failing to do it properly. Find below the simplest example that reproduces the problem:

```
Simplify[R,Assumptions->{R==IdentityMatrix[2]}]
```

which results in

> {{R11, R12}, {R21, R22}}

I would expect Mathematica to produce the identity matrix because

```
Simplify[x,Assumptions->{x==1}]
```

produces

> 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The leave count of R is smaller than that of {{1,0},{0,1}}

Comment: `Simplify[R, 
 Assumptions -> Flatten@MapThread[Equal, {R, IdentityMatrix[2]}, 2]]`

Comment: Thanks @march. Your proposal solves my problem :)